# eclipse oxygen + weblogic 12.2.1.3 - new server runtime environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

I've downloaded the weblogic (12.2.1.3) quick installer and installed.

In eclispe (oxygen), I've installed the Oracle Weblogic Server tool plugin (17.0.0.201709131633).

I'm trying to add  New Server Runtime -> Oracle Weblogic Server. In the dialog, I have tried adding the weblogic install directory and the wlserver directory (c:\oraclexe\wls12213\wlserver). Eclipse says "... does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install or the installed version is not supported.". Oracles website says "Full support for versions 9.2 through 12.1.3.".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are.

> Oracles website says "Full support for versions 9.2 through 12.1.3"

And you are using a later version :

> 12.2.1.3

Comment: Ha ha, my dodgy eye site made me miss the second '2'. Thanks for pointing out the blatant error. FYI, I have since found it does support 12.2.1.2.

Comment: @TedTrippin : Can you please post the solution for 12.2.x? How did you solve it?

Comment: By using 12.2.1.2 instead of 12.2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, finally I had to use Weblogic 12.1.3 integrated to my eclipse Oxygen, using java 1.8 (for local development environment). On our production infrastructure we have installed Weblogic 12.2.1.3, and the auto generated .ear runs on 12.1.3, it also works well on 12.2.1.3